# при клике на ссылку открыть блок и остальные скрыть

Tags: javascript

даны блоки и ссылки -
при клике на определенную ссылку - нужно открыть блок. все остальные скрыть. как это реализовать на JS?

```js
const a = document.querySelectorAll('a');

a.forEach( a => {
  a.addEventListener('click', show);
);

function show(elem) {
  this.classList.toggle("active");
  let second = this.nextElementSibling;
  elem.style.display === "none" ? elem.style.display = "" : elem.style.display == "none";
}
```

```css
.tab1, .tab2, .tab3, .tab4 {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion__wrap">
    <ul class="accordion__list">
        <li class="accordion__items"> <a href="#tab1"> First Training Class</a></li>
        <li class="accordion__items"> <a href="#tab2"> Second Training Class</a></li>
        <li class="accordion__items"> <a href="#tab3"> Third Training Class</a></li>
        <li class="accordion__items"> <a href="#tab4"> Fourth Training Class</a></li>
    </ul>    
</div>
<div class="accordion__wrap tabs">
    <article id="tab1" class="tab1">
        <h2>First</h2>
        <img src="img/1.jpg" alt="">
        <p>Phasellus convallis mauris sed elementum vulputate. Donec posuere leo sed dui eleifend hendrerit. Sed suscipit suscipit erat, sed vehicula ligula. Aliquam ut sem fermentum sem tincidunt lacinia gravida aliquam nunc. Morbi quis erat imperdiet, molestie nunc ut, accumsan diam</p>
    </article>
    <article  id="tab2" class="tab2">
        <h2>Second</h2>
        <img src="img/2.jpg" alt="">
        <p>Phasellus convallis mauris sed elementum vulputate. Donec posuere leo sed dui eleifend hendrerit. Sed suscipit suscipit erat, sed vehicula ligula. Aliquam ut sem fermentum sem tincidunt lacinia gravida aliquam nunc. Morbi quis erat imperdiet, molestie nunc ut, accumsan diam</p>
    </article>
    <article id="tab3" class="tab3">
        <h2>Third</h2>
        <img src="img/3.jpg" alt="">
        <p>Phasellus convallis mauris sed elementum vulputate. Donec posuere leo sed dui eleifend hendrerit. Sed suscipit suscipit erat, sed vehicula ligula. Aliquam ut sem fermentum sem tincidunt lacinia gravida aliquam nunc. Morbi quis erat imperdiet, molestie nunc ut, accumsan diam</p>
    </article>
    <article id="tab4" class="tab4">
        <h2>Fourth</h2>
        <img src="img/4.jpg" alt="">
        <p>Phasellus convallis mauris sed elementum vulputate. Donec posuere leo sed dui eleifend hendrerit. Sed suscipit suscipit erat, sed vehicula ligula. Aliquam ut sem fermentum sem tincidunt lacinia gravida aliquam nunc. Morbi quis erat imperdiet, molestie nunc ut, accumsan diam</p>
    </article>
</div>
```

Comment: Разделите на задачи: 1. Найти href атрибут (значение) у нажатого эл-та. 2. По значению атрибута найти эл-т который ему соответствует. 3.  найденному эл-ту меняем стили. 4. всем остальным меняем стили (скрываем). Лучше всего стили добавлять/убирать через класс, а не напрямую element.style прописывать

Comment: @InDevX благодарю буду пробовать.